# PHPMYADMIN exported UTF-16 Character set contains ? character in the first field

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I exported in PHPMyAdmin option using UTF-16 Character set. (I used this character set because other character sets truncate the text field) It's look like below.

> "Add","33649","CIPA 49704, 5",,"<ul>

The export file saved as CSV file. I opened another excel and delimited with Comma (,) and save the result in CSV file. And i opened the CSV file and it look like below

> ?"Add"    33649   CIPA 49704, 5       "<ul>

Why this `?` Symbol is appearing? I am confused.

Comment: it could be the BOM.

Comment: didn't get you, how to resolve that?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16

Comment: Is your text editor UTF-aware?

Comment: didn't get you about UTF in text editor

Comment: Some text editors know about UTF characters and can display them, others can't. Which text editor are you using?